# set default locale in lwuit?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

How to set default locale in lwuit(J2ME) and then how to change the default locale in lwuit? I'm using resource file for localization strings. Can any one give idea to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to change from your coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I will try to solve your issue.

To set a locale to yout LWUIT app you need to use `Hashtable` wich have your texts' values.
Are you using the Resource Editor? It will be helpfull for you in this moment. In the Resource editor you can build a table, in several columns, that have all your values ​​in the various languages

You must use the L10N values. You should catch them and use it like this:

```
Hashtable h = res.getL10N("NameOfYourL10N", "languageColumName"); 
UIManager.getInstance().setResourceBundle(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't change the locale through your Java ME coding. LWUIT allows to create multiple locale on ResourceEdit and you can read that locale from ResourceEdit. To identify the phone's current locale, use this code,

```
System.getProperty("microedition.locale");
```

Comment: locale represents a specific geographical and also I modified my answer.